# PowerShell - What's the use of global variables?

Tags: powershell, global-variables

Normally, this is a trivial question that can be answered with a simple search for most of the programing languages, but in PowerShell, it's not so easy.

If, by including a script via dot sourcing or including a module, their script variables are transferred into the calling script, than what's the point of having global variables?

Can someone clarify that for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not only variables that have a scope, function definitions too.

The benefit of having things global is that everyone can use them. Imagine you're importing a module which defines a few functions and you could not use them.

Regarding global variables in modules ... I'd rarely use them, except when they could control certain behaviour, like the various `*Preference` variables PS already has.

When dot-sourcing a script you're not making the scope global necessarily, by the way. Dot-sourcing simply executes a script *in the current scope* instead of creating one for the script. So when dot-sourcing something in a function you'd get the things from the script only in that function.

Comment: It can be used to share data with other commands even after the command who created them is no longer available.

Comment: Oops, @Andrei looks like I've overwritten your comment. Can you add it again?

Comment: No, it's ok. I've removed my comment because the new version of the answer contained the response to my question, so the comment wasn't necessary anymore.

I understand now. Thank you.

Comment: Aha, for some reason I thought I've deleted it :)